# What are the advantages of NServiceBus over MSMQ?

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I know this as been asked but couldn't find an answer that I understand...

Some people told me about the main thing are sagas, but it doesn't look such a big advantage to make me spend my bucks on NServiceBus when I already have MSMQ....

Comment: "advantages" is subjective to your requirements. Could you provide us a bit more information about what you're trying to achieve? Then we might be able to offer some insight as to how NServiceBus may, or may not, be beneficial to you.

Answer (score 4):

That's a little bit like asking "why do I need ASP.NET MVC when I already have HTTP?"... a little tongue-in-cheek, but still with a lot of truth in it.

NServiceBus gives you message serialization, a sensible threading model, routing, and several ready-to-use messaging patterns out of the box.

MSMQ gives you... message queues! And a fairly complicated API with many low level options that give you no real [pit of succes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/10/02/50420.aspx)...

Comment: I'm a beginner on this, I appreciate your help, so I think time will put the answer on my brain...